# How to put an input in a function

Tags: python, function, input

I tried to place an input in a function, but when I tried this it didn't work.
Can anyone tell me why?

```
def odd(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print("this number is even")
    else:
        print("this number is odd")

print("give a number")

x = input()
a = chance(x)
print(a)
```

This error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "words.py", line 10, in <module>
    a = chance(x)
NameError: name 'chance' is not defined
```

Comment: error is clear `chance` isn't defined, your function name is `odd`, also you don't return a value in your function so `a` isn't assigned anything, additionally you're passing a string from `input`, you're then trying to treat this as an `int` with `if x % 2`, you need to cast `x` to an `int`: `if int(x) % 2 == 0:`

Comment: The error message is in plain and clear english. You need to explain which part of it you don't understand if you want us to do more than just restate the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are never defining the function you're trying to call.
2. You're printing from the function but never returning a value, thus your variable "a" will never get a value.

Take a look at this, hopefully you'll see where you went wrong:

```
def odd(x):
    if int(x) % 2 == 0:
        return("this number is even")
    else:
        return("this number is odd")

x = input("Enter number")
print(odd(x))
```

Good luck! :)

To further answer your question "how to put an input in a function" (which was never actually done in the first place), you could instead do it like this which would give you the same result.

```
def odd():
    x = input("Enter number ") 
    if int(x) % 2 == 0:
        return("this number is even")
    else:
        return("this number is odd")

print(odd())
```